Error al conectar phpMyAdmin con Railway
Tengo un contenedor en Railway con un servidor MySQL al que quiero conectarme, ya configuré los datos para la conexión en el archivo configinc.php de la siguiente forma:
/**Second server*/
$i++;
/* Authentication type and info */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'agendaUser';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = 'KFgHmXmfEBtwHwBpPAnZswCobZgZassv';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysqli';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = false;
$cfg['Lang'] = 'es';
$cfg['port'] = '3306';

/* Bind to the localhost ipv4 address and tcp */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'mysql://agendaUser:KFgHmXmfEBtwHwBpPAnZswCobZgZassv@mysql.railway.internal:3306/agenda';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'tcp'; 

Hasta aquí todo bien, pero cuando selecciono el servidor e introduzco las credenciales para conectarme me sale esto

mysqli::real_connect(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Host desconocido.
mysqli::real_connect(): (HY000/2002): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Host desconocido.
El valor del host es el da la variable de entorno MYSQL_URL de mi servidor de producción, ya intenté también con los valores de MYSQL_PUBLIC_URL y MYSQL_HOST pero todos me dicen lo mismo, no sé cual hay que ponerle para que reconozca la dirección del servidor

Por favor, además de la imagen, pon el error como texto debajo de esta.

El error menciona que no has sido autorizado al servidor, por lo que hay que verificar.
Documentación de PhpMyAdmin -> https://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/config.html#cfg_Servers_host

$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host']
El nombre de host o la dirección IP de su servidor MySQL número $i. Por ejemplo, localhost.
Los valores posibles son:
nombre de host, por ejemplo, 'localhost' o 'mydb.example.org'
dirección IP, por ejemplo, '127.0.0.1' o '192.168.10.1' dirección
IPv6, por ejemplo, 2001:cdba:0000:0000:0000:0000:3257:9652 punto -
'.', es decir, usar pipes nombrados en sistemas Windows vacío - '',
desactiva este servidor

Según los posibles valores, tu host está mal configurado.
Tendría que ser más parecido a esto:
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie'; // Tipo de autenticación
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'mysql.railway.internal'; // Host del servidor MySQL en Railway
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['port'] = '3306'; // Puerto de MySQL (asegúrate de que sea correcto)
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'agendaUser'; // Usuario de MySQL en Railway
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = 'KFgHmXmfEBtwHwBpPAnZswCobZgZassv'; // Contraseña de MySQL en Railway
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysqli'; // Extensión PHP para MySQL
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = false; // Permitir conexión sin contraseña


Ya lo intenté también así pero me sigue diciendo lo mismo

Peobaste a poner la IP in ves de la URL ?
